# Trying to convert bool type to char of [yY, nN]

Tags: c#

I've new to c# and I've been working on this assignment to take multiple inputs from the user, store the data, then return the data in a certain format. Part of the assignment requirements is to prompt the user to enter a Y or N while it'll accept y or n as well. Is it cordless? [Y or N]:

I've tried using `Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().ToLower());` but I keep receiving

> cannot implicitly convert char to bool

Comment: You have a string (from ReadLine), you don't need to convert it to a char. Instead, compare it to the string `"y"` using `==`. Food for thought, what happens if someone enters "Yes" (which is a perfectly good answer for a `Y/N` prompt, or gets confused and answers "Blue")?

Comment: @Flydog57 THANK YOU! The solution was as simple as that and I've been beating around the bush for quite some time. To answer your question basically it'll just treat it as false since there is nothing explicitly that'll say do otherwise. I'm just starting to learn and think this was quite challenging as I spent hours trying to make it to perform exactly as the instructor asked. Again thank you so much!

Comment: Don't edit your question to say "it has been resolved" - post your own answer saying how you did it. Maybe one of your class mates stuck on the same thing will benefit from your advice. Share the knowledge; saying "oh I fixed this but I'm not saying how" doesn't help others

Comment: @CaiusJard I've included the solution. Hopefully this'll help someone else. And you're right. Also, someone might see my solution and suggest an alternative.

Comment: You can post it as an answer to your own question and (eventually) accept that answer so the question shows that it’s been answered.

Comment: don't include the answer in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I've seen your answer, I understand your question.. I would have made a method that asks for a string and repeats the question if the input is bad:

```
public string AskString(string q, string validAnswers[]){

  while(true) {
    Console.Write(q);
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    if(validAnswers == null){
      return input; //if no restriction, every answer is valid
    } else {
      foreach(string a in validAnswers) {
        if(input.Equals(a, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){
          return input;
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

And then use it for every question:

```
string drillMake = AskString("make? ", null);
string warranty = AskString("warranty, enter 12,24 or 36? ", new string[] {"12", "24", "36"})
string cordless = AskString("cordless, enter Y or N? ", new string[] {"y", "n"});

bool cordlessBool = cordless.Equals("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: This is really helpful! As I mentioned earlier I'm just starting to learn and using a condition statement directly seemed to be the easiest. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but methods are best suited to be used if you're going to reference them throughout the code, right?

Comment: Yep, I figured that your program would ask the user for more than one thing, so starting with a "method that prints a question and get sthe answer and returns it" is a good step 1.. Then you augment it with "repeat the question if it's bad input".. then you add other versions of it that get integers and booleans.. Then... And that's kinda how programs grow. You can strip it all away if you want, and just use a simple `string inp = Console.ReadLine(); bool cordless = inp.StartsWith("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` if you want :D

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It is making more sense to me. I'll try to improve my code by using your method for personal development. For the sake of the assignment I didn't need to repeat the question if the input was incorrect but this is definitely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var userInput = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
var cordless = userInput == "y";
```

or

```
var cordless = Console.ReadLine().ToLower() == "y";
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll accept Y/y as true otherwise it'll be false

```
        Console.Write("Is it cordless? [Y or N]: ");

        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        
        if (userInput == "Y")
        {
            hasCord = true;
        }
        else if (userInput == "y")
        {
            hasCord = true;
        }
```

Comment: Erm.. if it's cordless Y then hasCord is false

Comment: I get where the confusion is coming from. Cordless is true in this case because it will print an out output where the true or false value are compared to Yes and No. once the program finishes that says Cordless: Yes which is true. Cordless: No which is false

Comment: Yea I was just pointing out that asking the user "Is it a cordless drill" and they say "yes", if you then store "hasCord=true" you're saying it has a cord, when it doesn't (because the user just said it's cordless).. The wonder arena of "picking good variable names" :D

Comment: The instructions included a method where the variable names were provided. As per instructions we were not allowed to change the signature of the method. I might've made it confusing the I implemented it. Regardless, the output was as required. I'll take that as a win :P